# Making (virtual) functions made innaccessible in intermediate base class accessible in most-derived class, well-defined?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct a {
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

struct b: a {
private:
    void f() override {
        std::cout << "b::f()\n";
    }
};

struct c: b {
public:
    using a::f;
};

int main() {
    ::c c;
    c.f();
}
```

This compiles and works as expected with `g++`, `clang` and `msvc`, i.e., print `b::f()`.

However, if I replace `a` and `b` by this:

```cpp
struct a {
    void f() { }
};

struct b: a {
private:
    using a::f;
};
```

...the code does not compile anymore with `gcc` but compiles fines with both `clang`, `clang-cl` and `msvc` (thanks StoryTeller and Adrian Mole). I get the following error (on the `using a::f;` line in `c`):

> error: '`void a::f()`' is inaccessible within this context

I cannot find a clear point in the standard about the behavior of `using a::f;` (in `c`) in these cases, so are the above well-defined by the standard?

**Note:** I am not talking about bringing something in the `public` scope of a class (like `using b::f` in `c` if `b::f` was protected), but really making members from the top-level class accessible in the most-derived class after these have been made inaccessible in an intermediate base class.

Comment: Interesting. When I tried your modification, Clang accepted it (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6712bd5503c6178d). GCC however acts as you reported.

Comment: Your code (the *second* version) compiles and runs OK with both `MSVC` and `clang-cl`. (I added a `std::cout << "a::f()\n";` line to the `f()` body, to be sure.)

Comment: Changing `struct a...` to `class a` reproduces your error (in MSVC)! Perhaps GCC is confused between default access for `struct` (public) and `class` (private)?

Comment: @AdrianMole I have no issue with replacing `struct` to `class` in MSVC 16. Maybe you forgot to also change inheritance: `class b: public a`?

Comment: @AdrianMole https://rextester.com/HONTX5374

Comment: @Holt I kept `struct b` as it is. Only changed the base `a` to a `class`. Just looking for clues.

Comment: @AdrianMole The default inheritance is different between `struct` and `class`, so if you do `class b: a`, you cannot access `a::f` in `c` because `a` is a `private` base of `b`.

Comment: Where is hiding in your code examples?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer "hiding" might not be the right term but `b` is "hiding" `f()`, i.e., you cannot do `::b b; b.f();` because `b::f` is private. Now that you say it, it's not "hiding" in the sense having a declaration hide a previous declaration.

Comment: Looks like a bug in g++. It seems like g++ "patches" `a` when it encounters `using a::f`.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Might be related, but I don't think it answers everything, it's more the opposite - at least the answer - like moving something from `public` to `private` scope.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer But how do you call changing *accessibility*? :) I will try to update the question, thanks.

Comment: I've retracted my dup flag, indeed, your question is not really related. I didn't read it carefully.

Comment: _But how do you call changing accessibility?_ I'd say "Restoring public acessibility"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe GCC is wrong to reject the modified code.

> **[namespace.udecl]**
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.udecl#1) Each using-declarator in a using-declaration introduces a set
>   of declarations into the declarative region in which the
>   using-declaration appears. The set of declarations introduced by the
>   using-declarator is found by performing qualified name lookup
>   ([basic.lookup.qual], [class.member.lookup]) for the name in the
>   using-declarator, excluding functions that are hidden as described
>   below.
>
> [3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.udecl#3) In a using-declaration used as a member-declaration, each
>   using-declarator's nested-name-specifier shall name a base class of
>   the class being defined. If a using-declarator names a constructor,
>   its nested-name-specifier shall name a direct base class of the class
>   being defined.

So first I'd note that paragraph 3 makes a distinction between a base and a direct base. Therefore we can name `a::f` in a using declaration. Secondly, according to paragraph 1, name lookup proceeds as one would expect

> **[class.qual]**
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.qual#1) If the nested-name-specifier of a qualified-id nominates a
>   class, the name specified after the nested-name-specifier is looked up
>   in the scope of the class ([class.member.lookup]), except for the
>   cases listed below. The name shall represent one or more members of
>   that class or of one of its base classes (Clause [class.derived]).
>
> **[class.member.lookup]**
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.member.lookup#1) Member name lookup determines the meaning of a name
>   (id-expression) in a class scope. Name lookup can result in an
>   ambiguity, in which case the program is ill-formed. For an
>   id-expression, name lookup begins in the class scope of this; for a
>   qualified-id, name lookup begins in the scope of the
>   nested-name-specifier. Name lookup takes place before access control.

So `a::f` is to be looked up only in the scope of `a` or its own base classes. It should not be looked up at all in `b`. I would argue that therefore the accessibility of the name `f` in `b` should not affect the accessibility of the name `f` in `a` when doing qualified name lookup.

In `a`, `f` is public. And so can be named by a qualified-id in any declarative region where `a` may be named. That includes `c`. And so the using declaration uses a valid name for a valid member of a base class. That is accessible in that declarative region. It is therefore valid.

As another data point, GCC has no problem with the accessibility of `a::f` in other uses. [For example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4942eb4e17dc76d), GCC allows forming a pointer to member to `a::f` inside the scope of `c`.

```
struct c: b {
public:
    c() {
        [[maybe_unused]] auto f = &a::f;
    };
};
```

So it clearly does not consider the name `a::f` inaccessible in all contexts due to `b`.

Comment: Thanks. This may answer the part about the discrepancy between gcc and clang/msvc for the non-virtual stuff. Maybe my question is not clear on that point, but I was also wondering where the standard define the behavior in the virtual case? In the non-virtual case, if `b` redefines `f`, then `c.f()` will call `a::f` (and not `b::f`), which is not the case in the virtual case... I'm kind of wondering why? Like I could expect a compiler/link error because `using a::f` would try to use the pure-virtual function. Maybe I should ask a different question if the intent is not clear...

Comment: @Holt - A using declaration only affects names and scope. It does not define a pure virtual function in `c`. It only adds a name. The virtual function is still dispatched as virtual function are, and it happens to be overridden.